# IONIC - Plataforma

Tags: ionic

Sou novo no IONIC, estou tentando gerar APK do projeto, porem não consigo, ao colocar o comando `ionic cordova buid android` carrega os dados, e mostra a mensagem:

```
Android Studio project detected
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can getit from: http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Esta instalado o `JDK` e existe o caminho da `JAVA_HOME`.
Poderia me ajudar, por favor.

Comment: Voce esta usando Windows como sistema? Tenta executar como administrador caso seja Windows

Comment: Estou usando o Windows sim e já entrei como Administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Na variável de ambiente JAVA_HOME é pra está setado o caminho do jdk e não do jre.